# php message using sessions

Tags: php, session, alert, messagebox

I am try to develop flash message using sessions in php
suppose on successfully delete query I am setting

```
$_SESSION["msg"]="record deleted successfully";
header("location:index.php");
```

and I have the following script on all pages which checks if msg variable is available it echo its value as below

```
if(isset($_SESSION["msg"]) && !empty($_SESSION["msg"]))
        {
            $msg=$_SESSION["msg"];
            echo "<div class='msgbox'>".$msg."</div>";
            unset($_SESSION['msg']); //I have issue with this line.
        }
```

if I comment

```
unset($_SESSION['msg']);
```

message is being displayed, but with this line message is not being displayed
what am I doing wrong, or any alternative.

Comment: Litte note: If a var is not empty, it implies the fact that it exists.

Comment: there's no way that unsetting the session variable AFTER you've done your echo could prevent the session value from being displayed. PHP is not capable of time travel. Make sure that you've done `session_start()` every where you're dealing with the session, BEFORE you deal with the session.

Comment: Maybe irrelevant, but I see 'msg' in your unset() sentence, instead of "msg" that I see in the rest of the code.

Comment: why the extra $msg=$_SESSION["msg"]; line? Just use echo "<div class='msgbox'>".$_SESSION["msg"]."</div>";

Answer (score 4):

You are saying that you have that script on every page. So my guess is that after you make header("location:index.php"); your code continues to run - your message is displayed and unset (you don't see it because of redirect to index.php). When you are redirected to index.php your message is already unset.

Try adding exit; after header("location:index.php");.

Edit: I will add two examples with one working and one not. To test you need access test page with following link - /index.php?delete=1

In this example you will never see message. Why? Because header function does not stop code execution. After you set your session variable and set your redirect your code continues to execute. That means your message is printed and variable unset too. When code finishes only than redirect is made. Page loads and nothing is printed because session variable was unset before redirect.

```
<?php
session_start();
// ... some code
if ($_GET['delete']==1) {
    $_SESSION["msg"] = "record deleted successfully";
    header("location: index.php");
}
// ... some code
if (isset($_SESSION["msg"]) && !empty($_SESSION["msg"])) {
    $msg = $_SESSION["msg"];
    echo "<div class='msgbox'>" . $msg . "</div>";
    unset($_SESSION['msg']);
}
// ... some code
?>
```

But this code probably will work as you want. Note that I have added exit after header line.
You set your message, tell that you want redirect and tell to stop script execution. After redirect your message is printed and unset as you want.

```
<?php
session_start();
// ... some code
if ($_GET['delete']==1) {
    $_SESSION["msg"] = "record deleted successfully";
    header("location: index.php");
    exit;
}
// ... some code
if (isset($_SESSION["msg"]) && !empty($_SESSION["msg"])) {
    $msg = $_SESSION["msg"];
    echo "<div class='msgbox'>" . $msg . "</div>";
    unset($_SESSION['msg']);
}
// ... some code
?>
```

You clearly said that you have that code (message printing) on all pages. If your code is similar to my example than adding exit should fix your problem.

Another problem might be that you are doing more than one redirect.

Comment: I am setting session variable on pages from where I have to generate message, and on every page I check if there is session set so I am doing 2 tasks 1- displaying msg 2- removing session var so that do not repeat on other pages

Comment: Updated answer. If this is not case than you should provide more code to see why you don't see your message.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set your session `empty` or `null` instead of unset it. Just do:

```
$_SESSION['msg']=NULL;
```

Or

```
$_SESSION['msg']="";
```

Comment: and now I have solved it by calling a php file(which has code to remove session) through ajax at the bottom of page